# undefined method `<<' for nil:NilClass rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, psql, rails-console

Hey i'm creating database schema and test it in rails console. I have relation **User has_many :rates** and **Rates belongs_to :user**. When I type in rails console:

```
user = User.find(1)
rate = Rate.find(1)
user.rates << rate
```

Every thing works fine, but when i want to do it in opposite way:

```
user2 = User.find(2)
rate2 = Rate.find(2)
rate2.user << user2
```

I've got an following error **NoMethodError: undefined method `<<' for nil:NilClass**

**Users Migration**

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.column "username", :string, :limit => 25 
      t.string "first_name", :limit => 30
      t.string "last_name", :limit => 50
      t.string "password" 
      t.date "date_of_birth" 
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

**Rates Migration**

```
class CreateRates < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :rates do |t|
      t.integer "user_id"
      t.integer "credibility", :limit => 1 #0 or 1
      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index("rates", "user_id")
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `user` attribute is not an array (or collection of any kind), you must assign to it.

```
user2 = User.find(2)
rate2 = Rate.find(2)
rate2.user = user2
```